# Unable to run aspectj example from Spring in action 4th

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have the following definition of an aspect and other classes that are co-working.

```
package concert;

public aspect CriticAspect {
    public CriticAspect() {}

    pointcut performance(): execution(* perform(..));


    afterReturning() : performance() {
        System.out.println(criticismEngine.getCriticism());
    }

    private CriticismEngine criticismEngine;

    public void setCriticismEngine(CriticismEngine criticismEngine) {
        this.criticismEngine = criticismEngine;
    }

}
```

**CriticismEngine**

```
package concert;

public interface CriticismEngine {
    String getCriticism();
}
```

**CriticismEngineImpl**

```
package concert;

public class CriticismEngineImpl implements CriticismEngine {
    public CriticismEngineImpl() {}

    public String getCriticism() {
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * criticismPool.length);
        return criticismPool[i];
    }

    // injected
    private String[] criticismPool;
    public void setCriticismPool(String[] criticismPool) {
        this.criticismPool = criticismPool;
    }
}
```

**Performance**

```
package concert;

public interface Performance {
    void perform();
}
```

**PerformanceImple**

```
package concert;

public class Concert implements Performance {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Playing a concert!");
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
package concert.config;

import concert.Concert;
import concert.CriticAspect;
import concert.CriticismEngine;
import concert.CriticismEngineImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CriticAspect criticAspect() {
        return CriticAspect.aspectOf();
    }

    @Bean
    public CriticismEngine criticismEngine() {
        CriticismEngineImpl criticismEngine = new CriticismEngineImpl();
        String[] criticisms = { "Worst performance ever!",
                                "I laughed, I cried, then I realized I was at the wrong show.",
                                "A must see show!" };
        criticismEngine.setCriticismPool(criticisms);
        return criticismEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public Concert concert() {
        return new Concert();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package concert;

import concert.config.ApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
        Performance concert = context.getBean("concert", Performance.class);
        concert.perform();
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:${springAopVersion}"
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjrt:${aspectJRuntimeVersion}"
compile "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectJWeaverVersion}"
```

But intellij says it cannot find `CriticAspect`. How I can run this example ? Or I'm doing something wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMO `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` does not make sense for a native AspectJ aspect. It only works for Spring AOP aspects. So you have two options:

- Either you compile your native AspectJ aspect right into your Spring application via *Ajc* (AspectJ compiler). In this case you do not need any annotations to get the aspects running, only *aspectjrt.jar* on the classpath during runtime.
- Or you go the canonical way described in the Spring manual (chapter 9.8) and use LTW (load-time weaving) for native AspectJ aspects. This can be enabled in your configuration via `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` or `<context:load-time-weaver/>`, respectively. See chapter 9.8.4, [Load-time weaving with AspectJ in the Spring Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-first-example).

Comment: As you can see `AspectJRuntime` is on my classpath. I removed `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and tried to add `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` however nothing helped.  I think the problem is with Intellij idea - it doesn't use aspectj runtime to run my program, because I still get the same error that intellij cannot find symbol and points to aspect class `CriticAspect`. I added ss of the error

Comment: For the aspect you need to use *Ajc* as a compiler (as I said in my answer), not *Javac*. Probably your project settings are incorrect. You need an AspectJ facet and the right compiler. I recommend to create a Maven project which builds outside IDEA or Eclipse, then just import it in either IDE. I doe that with most of my AspectJ projects because IDEA has very good Maven support.