# Cannot resolve property "criticismEngine" error in Spring xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, spring-aop

I have taken this example from the book on Spring and it should create an instance of the aspect "СriticAspect" with a help of a static aspectOf() method, but I get "Cannot resolve property "criticismEngine" error while configuring CriticAspect in xml, although there is such a property in CriticAspect class.

XML config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="concert"/>
    <context:load-time-weaver/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean class="concert.Audience"/>
    <bean id="show" class="concert.Show" ><aop:scoped-proxy /></bean>
    <bean id="criticismEngine"
          class="concert.CriticismEngineImpl">
          <property name="criticismPool">
            <list>
                <value>Worst performance ever</value>
                <value>I laughed, I cried</value>
                <value>A must see show!</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="concert.CriticAspect"
          factory-method="aspectOf" >
        <property name="criticismEngine" ref="criticismEngine"  />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Aspect CriticAspect looks like:

```
package concert;

public aspect CriticAspect {

    private CriticismEngine criticismEngine;

    public CriticAspect(){}

    pointcut performance() : execution(* perform(..));

    after()returning: performance(){
        System.out.println(criticismEngine.getCriticism());
    }

    public void setCriticismEngine(CriticismEngine criticismEngine){
        this.criticismEngine=criticismEngine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide exact text of the error you got, please?

Comment: Cannot resolve property 'criticismEngine' Spring XmL model validation. It is red-lighted in IDEA.

Comment: Does the application work as intended when you run it?

Comment: Not really. I'm getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type [concert.Show] is defined.

Comment: @Tiana Seems like you have a mistake in aspect code: `after()returning: performance()` -> `after()returning: performance()`

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29455813/1082681) which was even about the very same code snippet from the same book:

I think that you need to decide whether to use

- Spring AOP via `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` or
- AspectJ via `<context:load-time-weaver/>`,

but not both together. You use native AspectJ syntax, so obviously you want to use the second option. Please try and see what happens if you remove the autoproxy statement from your XML configuration.

Please also note that in order to compile native AspectJ code, you need to use the AspectJ compiler *ajc*, not just *javac*.

Comment: like you said I've used load-time weaver and enabled ajc compiler. Still I got a mistake "Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver' ". It seems that my loadTimeWeaver isn't defined. I've tried @EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED) to use the default loadTimeWeaver, but it never helped.

Answer (score 0):

Like @kriegaex said your aspect has pure `AspectJ` syntax and in this case you must use `ajc` to compile this aspect code. If you do so, and also compile all of your code with `ajc`, then there is no need additional AOP configuration in Spring context, AspectJ will make all the work. Classes will be woven with your aspect at compile time on bytecode level.

So if you decide to use this approach then you must do the following (example below using Maven build):

**First** ensure that your aspect code is in the right place `src/main/aspectj/CriticAspect.aj;`

**Second** enable `AspectJ` runtime and compiler in `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            <source>${java.source}</source>
            <target>${java.target}</target>
            <complianceLevel>${java.target}</complianceLevel>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <verbose>false</verbose>
            <XnoInline>false</XnoInline>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>aspectj-compile</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>aspectj-compile-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Third** Now you can define your aspect in *Spring application context* like you do to enable dependency injection. Your Spring XML configuration file must look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="concert"/>

    <bean class="concert.Audience"/>
    <bean id="show" class="concert.Show"/>
    <bean id="criticismEngine"
          class="concert.CriticismEngineImpl">
          <property name="criticismPool">
            <list>
                <value>Worst performance ever</value>
                <value>I laughed, I cried</value>
                <value>A must see show!</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="concert.CriticAspect"
          factory-method="aspectOf" >
        <property name="criticismEngine" ref="criticismEngine"  />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Note** that in this case you must remove `<context:load-time-weaver/>` and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` from `applicationContext.xml` or any other Spring configuration.